# How to open a window from the same solution?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have MainWindow with a button, under the button click event I want MainWindow to open Window1, another window I have created beforehand. What is the simplest way to do this? Also I have a canvas in Window1 that I want to display a page (Page1) on a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If' i understood your question, then acc. to me:

MainWindow.vb - Create a handler for Click event of Button

```
Public Sub Button_Click ( ... )

    Dim window1 as new Window1(True) ' Create Window1 with isMainWindow = true and display it as a dialog.
    window1.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

Window1.vb - Create a bool property to check if initiated by MainWindow with isMainWindow = true.

```
Public Sub New(isMainWindow As Boolean)
    ...
    If (isMainWindow) Then
        MyCanvas.Children.Add(new Page1());
    End If
    ...
End Public
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I did realise I should be using grids (I think) rather than a canvas, but then I get another couple of errors entirely.

Comment: But why are you adding Page to canvas, cavas is generally for graphics related stuff ? What's error ?

Comment: `Private Sub btnCyl_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnCyl.Click

        Greg.Children.Clear()
        Greg.Children.Add(CylPage)
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnMix_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnMix.Click

        Greg.Children.Clear()
        Greg.Children.Add(MixPage)
    End Sub`

Comment: I'm now using grid instead of canvas. I have the error "MixPage is a type and cannot be used as a expression". Yet it's fine for CylPage.

Comment: What is MixPage and CylPage here ? Defined in XAML of this code ?

Comment: You have to use it like this, Greg.Children.Add(New MixPage) If it's not defined anywhere in your .vb file.

Comment: The error is because you are not creating a instance for MixPage, think like this MiXPage in a code file is just definition. You need make object of it before using

Comment: Okay. I get what you mean, but how do I do that?

Comment: Ok just chage this `Greg.Children.Add(MixPage)` to `Greg.Children.Add(New MixPage)`